# Fire javascript (lightbox) once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey all  I have a quick javascript question! Frustrated trying to get it sorted.... right now my modal div shows after 10 seconds which is right, but I want to only show it **ONCE** per session.  Here's my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() { // wait for the DOM
setTimeout(function () {
    var $modal = $('#free-awesome'); // your selector; cache it; only query the DOM once!

    $modal.modal('show'); // show modal; this happens after 10 seconds 

    setTimeout(function () {
        $modal.modal('hide'); // hide modal; 
    }, 50000);    
}, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can adapt that javascript to show once per visit/session?

I'm quite new to javascript so if you could let me know exactly what to swap the above  out for that'd be great!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage):

```
if(!sessionStorage.hidemodal) {
    // your code ...

    sessionStorage.hidemodal = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works but when I revisit i'd like the modal to show again ?

i.e. it'd be good to only show once per visit